# arr.reduce shows the shortest length instead of the longest length

Tags: javascript, reduce

i followed the code under **3. Find the Longest Word With the reduce() Method** [source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/three-ways-to-find-the-longest-word-in-a-string-in-javascript-a2fb04c9757c/)

why does the result show 2 instead of 5? my logic as follows:

- longest.length = 0 ("") > currentWord.length = 5 (howss) -> false, output 5
- longest.length = 5 (howss) > currentWord.length = 5 (fuund) -> false, output 5 (fuund)
- longest.length = 5 (fuund) > currentWord.length = 2 (se) -> true, output 5 (fuund)

```js
let arr = ['howss', 'fuund', 'se']
let longestLength = arr.reduce((longest, currentWord) => 
  longest.length > currentWord.length ? 
  longest.length : currentWord.length , "")

console.log(longestLength)
```

also, how do i shift line 97 to start from the same position as line 92 in the image below? the formatting currently shows that line 97 is a part of line 93. the code runs fine however

[line 97 classified as part of line 93](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP33O.png)

Comment: You are returning the `length` not the string, so the next iteration you are going to be testing against `undefined` since a number has no `length`

Comment: Do you want to return (and use as accumulator, and as initial value) a string or a length?

Comment: @PatrickEvans by "a number has no `length`" do u mean "a string has no `length`"? if so, i ran the following and the output was 0: `let test =""` `console.log(test.length)`

Comment: @Bergi i want to return length

Comment: No I mean number. Your ternary is returning a number not your strings, so on the next iteration `longest` is going to be a number not a string

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes which is the same as the logic i provided right? ie the next iteration `longest` is 0,5 and 5

Comment: You can't use `longest.length` after the first iteration as `longest` will then be a number and not a string. And as said numbers don't have a `length` property, eg `(2).length == undefined`

Comment: @nubprog Then also start with `0` (or `-Infinity` or something) as the initial value (instead of `""`), and use a `length` parameter instead of the `longest` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The accumulator in the `reduce` function should be an `number` representing the length of the longest word so far, initially set to zero:

```js
const arr = ['howss', 'fuund', 'se'];

const longestLength = arr.reduce((longestLen, currentWord) => 
  longestLen > currentWord.length ? longestLen : currentWord.length
, 0);

console.log(longestLength);
```

If you want to set to as a `string` representing the longest word, you will need to compute it first, and then get the `length` after the loop ends:

```js
const arr = ['howss', 'fuund', 'se'];

const longestLength = arr.reduce((longestWord, currentWord) => 
  longestWord.length > currentWord.length ? longestWord : currentWord
, "").length;

console.log(longestLength);
```

Comment: i followed the same code under "3. Find the Longest Word With the reduce() Method" and their logic was the same as what i posted [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/three-ways-to-find-the-longest-word-in-a-string-in-javascript-a2fb04c9757c/)

Comment: They are getting the longest word first, and then returning its length. This is why I presented to solutions, either have the accumulator representing the longest length, or the longest word. But you need to decide what are you updating

Answer (score 1):

1. Your intial value is an empty string - it should be zero so that you can add length values to it (the accumulator - *`longest`*) on each iteration.
2. There's no need to assign the length of `currentWord` to `longest.length` since `longest` is a single value. Just increment `longest`, and return it for the next iteration.

```js
let arr = ['howss', 'fuund', 'se', 'guardian'];

let longestLength = arr.reduce((longest, currentWord) => {
  if (currentWord.length > longest) {
    longest = currentWord.length;
  }
  return longest;
}, 0);

console.log(longestLength)
```

Honestly, though, I wouldn't even use `reduce` for this.

```js
const arr = ['howss', 'fuund', 'se', 'guardian'];

let len = 0;

for (let el of arr) {
  if (el.length > len) len = el.length;
}

console.log(len);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning an empty string with each iteration and compare it to the next item. What you could do is return actual longest string and at final iteration return it's length;

```js
let arr = ['se', 'howss', 'fuund','test', "a"]
let longestLength = arr.reduce((longest, currentWord, i, a) => ((longest = longest.length > currentWord.length ? 
  longest : currentWord), i == a.length-1 ? longest.length : longest))

console.log(longestLength)
```

Comment: `i` refers to the index of `arr` and `a.length` refers to the length of `arr`? what does `i == a.length-1 ? longest.length : longest` do? could you show the step by step for this line?

Comment: That is correct, `i` is index at which the current data is and `a` is a reference to actual array. I've used `a` to make it universal so it can be used for any array with any names. Basically what this does is check if current iteration is the last item in the array, if so it returns final answer, otherwise it returns currently longest string itself.
This is not the best answer, it's just another method can be applied to the task.